# condition display the logout button in frame

Tags: javascript, html

I've a webapp that uses the following frameset code to display frames on all its webpages.  The myAccountTopFrame.jsp frame in the frameset contains a logout button that the user can click to logout from the site.  This logout button is being displayed on all webpages, including the login page.  I wonder if there is a way to display this logout button on all pages except the login page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <frameset rows="31px,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">  
    <frame src="myAccountTopFrame.jsp" name="top" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" >
    <frame src="<%=iFrameSrc%>" name="bottom" frameborder="0" style="display:block; align:top;">
  </frameset> 
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using frames? It looks like it is just for the layout. If yes, you should rather have a main jsp and use includes.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to resolve the issue:

1) Add onload="toggleLogoutButton()" to the "bottom" frame.

2) Add toggleLoutoutButton JS to hide or display logout button base on the "bottom" frame path.

See below:

```
<frameset rows="31px,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">  
  <frame src="myAccountTopFrame.jsp" name="top" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
  <frame src="<%=iFrameSrc%>" name="bottom" frameborder="0" style="display:block; align:top;" onload="toggleLogoutButton()">
</frameset> 

function toggleLogoutButton() {
  try {         
    // get the current location
    var currentPath = window.frames[1].location.pathname;

    // hide logout button if in login page.  Otherwise, show it. 
    if (currentPath.toLowerCase() == "/login2.jsp" || currentPath.toLowerCase() == "/login_outage.jsp")
      window.frames[0].document.getElementById("logoutButton").style.display="none";
    else {
      window.frames[0].document.getElementById("logoutButton").style.display="inline";
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
  }
```